# What Step Am I missing in this trig expression?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $$\frac{p(\cos(x) - p)}{1 - 2p\cos(x)+p^2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1 - p^2}{1 - 2p\cos(x) + p^2} - 1 \right)$$  I'm unsure as to the steps to take to show that it is equivalent.

Comment: Write a common denominator on the right side.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685705/what-steps-are-taken-to-make-this-complex-expression-equal-this

Answer (score 1):

Start from the RHS by adding the terms in the bracket.
$$\frac{1-p^2}{1-2p\cos x+p^2}-\frac{1-2p\cos x+p^2}{1-2p\cos x+p^2}$$
Simplify.
$$\frac{1-p^2-(1-2p\cos x+p^2)}{1-2p\cos x+p^2}=\frac{2p\cos x-2p^2}{1-2p\cos x+p^2}$$
Factor out $2p$.
$$\frac{2p(\cos x-p)}{1-2p\cos x+p^2}$$
Multiply by half and you'll get the LHS.